# Getting docstring in QPython3

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, docstring, qpython3

So far all the modules I tested (all in the standard Python library) do not print anything when I run `__doc__`.

`help()` works, but I am after `__doc__` specifically.

I have tried this without success:

```
/mnt/expand/57a15ba6-0cc9-4f25-a0b0-a1375e612c7a/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/bin/qpython-android5.sh && exit
files/bin/qpython-android5.sh && exit   <
Python 3.2.2 (default, Jun 18 2015, 19:03:02)
[GCC 4.9 20140827 (prerelease)] on linux-armv7l
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
WARNING: linker: /mnt/expand/57a15ba6-0cc9-4f25-a0b0-a1375e612c7a/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/libreadline.so.6: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x316a
>>>
>>>import re
>>>re.__doc__
>>>
>>>print(re.__doc__)
None
>>>
```

But nothing has been printed.  I am running QPython on Android 6.0.1.

How do I get a docstring (`__doc__`) in QPython3?

Comment: It doesn't look like QPython actually has docstrings.

Comment: (Also, 3.2.2? Bleh.)

Comment: @user2357112  So the only way forward is `help()`?  Yeah I don't think they provide a 3.6 version yet.